# Emacs shell-command outputting "cannot set terminal process group" and "no job control in this shell"

Tags: bash, emacs, debian

When I run shell-command in Emacs on Debian 6.0 (Squeeze), e.g.

```lisp
(shell-command "ls")
```

the output is preceded with

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument
bash: no job control in this shell
```

This is particularly annoying when applying a shell command (e.g. perltidy) to a buffer, as those lines end up on the top of the buffer.

This is a newly installed Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) system with the latest emacs from apt-get.

```
% uname -a
Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 00:01:30 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
% emacs --version
GNU Emacs 23.2.1
% dpkg -l | grep emacs
ii  emacs                                   23.2+1-7
ii  emacs23                                 23.2+1-7 
ii  emacs23-bin-common                      23.2+1-7 
ii  emacs23-common                          23.2+1-7 
ii  emacsen-common                          1.4.22
```

Happy to provide other information as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind, it was because of this:

```
(set-variable 'shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

Comment: It passes "-ic" to the shell, meaning that the shell is supposed to behave as an interactive shell ("-i") and it is to read commands from the string following "-c".

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is more to the story. See the problem reported at http://old.nabble.com/bash-under-emacs-gives-%22cannot-set-terminal-process-group%22-to33399261.html#a33399456 (and that is for the Cygwin environment but the underlying bug may affect bash behavior on both Linux and on Cygwin).

Comment: Link seems to be dead. web.archive.org suggests this one instead: http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/bash-under-emacs-gives-quot-cannot-set-terminal-process-group-quot-td6734.html